# object dies in a loop c++ simple list

Tags: c++, eclipse, loops, operator-overloading

I have a list of Movie class, and I want to add them all together into one Movie instance. problem is, from that loop doesn't do the operator + as expected becuase it runs over a list of pointers that's inside, copying only the rest of the data. operator+ must be fine, because when I add Movies without using a loop it performs as expected, so I will leave it empty and post here the return value and arguments.

the loop is (Movie final is a class member)

```
   Movie g,temp;
   int i=0;
   //moviesToAdd is a list, performing as expected (checked before)

   for (std::list<Movie>::iterator it2=moviesToAdd.begin(); i != 
   moviesToAdd.size(); ++it2) 
    {
        temp=final;
        i++;
        g = *it2;
       final =  temp + g;

      if(i==moviesToAdd.size())
         {
          break;
         }                  
    }//end for*/
```

this is operator +, = who work perfectly fine so I leave only this:

```
Movie Movie:: operator+ (const Movie& other) const{
Movie toReturn;
////some code///
return toReturn; }

Movie& Movie:: operator= (const Movie& other) {
///////some code////
return *this; }
```

as I mentioned - they work as well not using this loop, so problem must be inheritted in this loop not being able to copy a list of pointers which is a class member of Movie.

HELP..?

Comment: Why don't you check `it2 != moviesToAdd.end()`, also if you write a `operator +=`, you can get rid of `temp` .

Comment: ok , i changed it.. still doesn't work with the loop

Comment: I wrote a small Movie class and tested your loop and it works, so maybe something is wrong in your Movie implementation. At any rate the way you are handling this loop is error prone. Could you update your question with a working example that gives you this issue?